# Trying to post a question, the screen reloads but nothing is posted

Tags: support, asking-questions

In total I have asked 9 questions. The last time that I have asked a question was roughly 22 hours ago, yet I still cannot ask questions. I deleted my old one to see if it would change anything but no success.

I don't get any message saying I cannot post or anything. When I click the button to post the questions the screen reloads but nothing changes. I am in compatibility mode on IE8 running windows xp, and have tried erasing my cache.

Why am I not able to post questions?

Comment: Cleared your cache?

Comment: What browser are you on? A quick google for "clear cache browsername" should reveal that...

Comment: Hmm...any JavaScript disabled? Somehow in compatibility mode?

Comment: @Chase: Please remember that comments, by their nature, are meant to be impermanent. Please [edit] your question to include important information rather than leaving it in the comments.

Comment: Get out of compatibility mode and try it again. That's most likely your problem.